# Not able to product page source

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, seo, server-side-rendering

In my nextjs project I am building page using getStaticProps and getStaticPath but not able to build html into page source which is causing lot of issues in SEO.
Haven't used redux-persist.
My _app.js

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";
import NextNProgress from "../components/NextNProgress";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../scss/index.scss";

const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: "########",
};
export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      typeof window !== "undefined" && (
        <>
          <NextNProgress />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
      )
    );
  }
}
```

My _document.js file

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const { html, head, errorHtml, chunks } = renderPage();

    return { html, head, errorHtml, chunks };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          ></link>
          <link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json" />
          <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            type="image/x-icon"
            href="/static/Images/favicon.ico"
          />
          <link
            rel="preload"
            href="/static/Images/DMI-Logo-White.png"
            as="image"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://www.google-analytics.com"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://www.googletagmanager.com"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="http://hn.inspectlet.com"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://msbs-dmi-img.s3.amazonaws.com"
            crossOrigin="anomynous"
          />
          <meta
            name="msvalidate.01"
            content="DAA15A8121AE0CF599E70877904DF215"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do to make html available in page source
I am getting page built and rendered properly but html isn't getting saved in page source and even page not rendering when javascript is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your code, you are not rendering the page during build time, but only during runtime. Would you try the following _app.js?

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";
import NextNProgress from "../components/NextNProgress";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../scss/index.scss";

const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: "########",
};

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <NextNProgress />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```